# Python capturing "HTTP status code" exception messages

Tags: json, python-3.x, http, try-catch

I am having problems error handling code when deleting a file from box.com using Box API. The code  establishes a connection to Box.com via JSON.

```
client.file(file_id=99999999999).delete()
```

When I run the command, the Box APIs uses HTTP status codes to communicate if a request has been successfully processed or not. This is what I see in PyCharm:

[Error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RMbF.png)

How do I use this error response (the red text in the bottom of the screen to handle errors so I can do something like this:

```
try: 
    client.file(file_id=xxxxxxxxxx).delete()
except 404:
    print('error 404 occurred')
except 405:
    print('error 405 occurred')
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `except BoxAPIException as e:` and accessing the properties through e? (e.g. `e.status`)

Answer (score 0):

@xaleel
I have tried this:

```
config = JWTAuth.from_settings_file(JSONFile)
client = Client(config)

try:
    client.file(file_id=99999999999).delete()
except BoxAPIException as e:
    print(e.status)
```

The error returned is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Temp\Box\Test\Test.py", line 20, in 
except BoxAPIException as e:
NameError: name 'BoxAPIException' is not defined. Did you mean: 'BaseException'?

I have also tried "BoxException". Is this case sensitive? where can I look to see the correct possible name to use? Sorry I am not a programmer and really new to Python. I just set myself this challenge to learn!

Comment: This section is for answers. If you have additional/clarifying information or want to show your attempted solution, it needs to be included in your question. You should edit your original question post and move this text there, and then delete this answer. Thanks.